# AWS Beanstalk Deployment Failing Due to WSGIPath

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy a Django application the AWS ElasticBeanstalk. However, my deployments are failing due to a possible error in WSGIPath. Here is my configuration in `/.ebextensions`:

```
option_settings:
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment":
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: "conf.settings"
    "PYTHONPATH": "/var/app/current:$PYTHONPATH"
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python":
    WSGIPath: conf.wsgi:application
    NumProcesses: 1
    NumThreads: 15
```

Here is the error that I encounter:

```
/var/log/web.stdout.log
----------------------------------------
Oct 28 04:17:54 ip-172-31-9-159 web: File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
Oct 28 04:17:54 ip-172-31-9-159 web: worker.init_process()
Oct 28 04:17:54 ip-172-31-9-159 web: File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/gthread.py", line 92, in init_process
Oct 28 04:17:54 ip-172-31-9-159 web: super().init_process()
Oct 28 04:17:54 ip-172-31-9-159 web: File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
Oct 28 04:17:54 ip-172-31-9-159 web: self.load_wsgi()
Oct 28 04:17:54 ip-172-31-9-159 web: File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
Oct 28 04:17:54 ip-172-31-9-159 web: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
Oct 28 04:17:54 ip-172-31-9-159 web: File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
Oct 28 04:17:54 ip-172-31-9-159 web: self.callable = self.load()
Oct 28 04:17:54 ip-172-31-9-159 web: File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
Oct 28 04:17:54 ip-172-31-9-159 web: return self.load_wsgiapp()
Oct 28 04:17:54 ip-172-31-9-159 web: File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
Oct 28 04:17:54 ip-172-31-9-159 web: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
Oct 28 04:17:54 ip-172-31-9-159 web: File "/var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 363, in import_app
Oct 28 04:17:54 ip-172-31-9-159 web: raise ImportError(msg % (module.rsplit(".", 1)[0], obj))
Oct 28 04:17:54 ip-172-31-9-159 web: ImportError: Failed to find application, did you mean 'conf/wsgi:application'?
```

My app structure looks basically like this:

```
backend-app/
├─ .ebextensions/
├─ conf/
│  ├─ settings.py
│  ├─ wsgi.py
│  ├─ ...
├─ my-app/
│  ├─ ....
├─ manage.py
```

I have tried multiple ways of specifying the WSGIPath according to some online resources, and the suggestion the error gives. I've tried changing it to `conf/wsgi.py`, `conf.wsgi.application`, `conf/wsgi`, `conf.wsgi`, `conf.wsgi:application`, and `conf/wsgi:application`. I'm not sure how to approach this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: same problem here

Comment: me too - did anybody figure this out?